# Adding the reactive Framework "Subject" to an interface

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

I was using Events in my class and added an event reference to the interface that my class was derived from. I have decided to use the Reactive framework and am now using the “Subject” type as shown below. I wanted to add this to the interface as all my functions pass around the interface but I get the error say I can’t add a field to an interface. Is there a way of exposing this new line of code in my interface or will I have to cast to the concrete type when subscribing ?

```
public Subject<PanelEventArguments> PanelEvt = new Subject<PanelEventArguments>();
```

Comment: Don't expose subjects on an interface. Anyone can call `OnCompleted` or `OnError` and cause you code to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you add it as a property?

Comment: In the interface do you mean?

Comment: I have added "IObservable<PanelEventArguments> PanelEventHandler { get; }" to the interface and added the "Get" code to the class. I can then access the property and call subscribe from it. Thanks for your help.